Definition of the single-particle density matrix
The single-particle density matrix is defined as
$$\rho_{ij } = \langle \psi | a_j^\dagger a_i |\psi \rangle . $$
I am curious about the order of the indices. Why is it not
$$ \rho_{ij } = \langle \psi | a_i^\dagger a_j |\psi \rangle $$
I know the first definition would lead to the compact expression of the expectation value of a single-particle operator $\mathcal{A} = \sum_{ij } A_{ij } a_i^\dagger a_j $,
$$\langle \psi| \mathcal{A} |\psi \rangle = \mathrm{Tr}\,(\rho A ).$$
But is there any more deep reason, a not so pragmatic one?

The quantity $\rho$ you are defining seems to the the covariance matrix. The density matrix here would be $|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$. And if it is the covariance matrix you are after, then it is typically defined as
$$\langle \psi| (a_j^\dagger a_i + a_i^\dagger a_j) |\psi\rangle / 2$$
so that it is Hermitian. The Hermiticity of $\mathcal{A}$ implies that $A$ is also Hermitian, so that the trace in your last formula gives a real number by default.

Your reason is correct. Also, it is the reduced density matrix if you trace out, in the quantum information sense, $N-1$ particles in a $N$ particle system (up to a factor $N$): The Hilbert space of $N$ identical fermions or bosons is a subspace of the $N$-fold tensor product of the single-particle Hilbert space $H_N=H_1\otimes H_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes H_1$. If you now take the partial trace of any of one of those factors, you get the 1-RDM (up to the factor $N$); in particular all reduced density operators (in the QI sense) of the single-particle Hilbert spaces are the same.

@KarenH. $\rho$ as defined in the question is hermitian anyway.
